# Java doesn't update mouse input while mouse is pressed?

Tags: java, mouse, updating, pressed

I need the mouse to update position even while the mouse is being pressed. This is my code so far and I'm not sure where to go from here to fix my problem:

This code is ran in my main loop and Mouse is a class I've created that implements MouseListener and MouseMotionListener that gets the position of the mouse coordinates and which mouse button was pressed.

When i press my mouse (I'm using a laptop, not sure if that matters or not) but it displays which button is pressed, which is good, but as I move my mouse around (with the button pressed) the white square that I have rendering where the mouse is, it just freezes up and doesn't move with the mouse. I have to release the mouse then move it again for it to get back where the mouse position is. Not sure what's going on here or how to fix it. I've been following java game tutorials on youtube from thecherno.

```
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics(); // bs is a bufferstrategy
{
  g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null); // my game image

  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  g.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 0, 20));
  g.fillRect(Mouse.getX() - 32, Mouse.getY() - 32, 64, 64);
  g.drawString("Button: " + Mouse.getButton(), 10, 30);
}
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

My mouse class

```
package rain.input;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private static int mouseX = -1;
    private static int mouseY = -1;
    private static int mouseB = -1;

    public static int getX() {
        return mouseX;
    }

    public static int getY() {
        return mouseY;
    }

    public static int getButton() {
        return mouseB;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseB = e.getButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseB = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What methods are you using for processing mouse events?

Comment: More code (e.g. the actual mouse event code) would be more helpful.

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy  I just added my Mouse class

Comment: @1blustone just added my Mouse class. It basically just returns the mouse position and which mouse button was pressed. Wait, I just noticed the mouseDragged method..I'm adding code to that now to see if that's the problem

Comment: Yes. mouseDragged() is the one that you should use.

Comment: It's so funny cause I'll be debugging stuff for at least an hour trying to figure it out and as soon as I pose to a forum I figure it out lol.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) method to get the coordinates of the mouse while the button is pressed.

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  mouseX = e.getX();
  mouseY = e.getY();
}
```